# ConfigServer Security Firewall & port forwarding

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have installed CSF "ConfigServer Security & Firewall" and cant figure out how to do port forwarding. Is there a tutorial or how to out there or can some one explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "/etc/csf/csf.redirect" file to setup port redirection.

```
# DNAT (redirect from one IP address to a different one):
# IPx|*|IPy|*|tcp/udp          - To IPx redirects to IPy
# IPx|portA|IPy|portB|tcp/udp  - To IPx to portA redirects to IPy portB
#
# DNAT examples:
# 192.168.254.62|*|10.0.0.1|*|tcp
# 192.168.254.62|666|10.0.0.1|25|tcp
#
# REDIRECT (redirect from port to a different one):
# IPx|portA|*|portB|tcp/udp    - To IPx to portA redirects to portB
# *|portA|*|portB|tcp/udp      - To portA redirects to portB
#
# REDIRECT examples:
# 192.168.254.60|666|*|25|tcp
# *|666|*|25|tcp
```